# how to align ul list as a buttons to the center

Tags: html, css

Good evening,
I've got an exercise to make a Header and buttons under it. We've got ready code for the buttons. Our goal is to put it in a border, make a header over these buttons and align buttons and header to center.

My code looks like this right now

CSS

```
ul {
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: auto;
    list-style: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 130px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aqua;
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    margin: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
}

li a:hover {
    color: blue;
    background: aqua;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.naglowek {
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Menu poziome</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="naglowek">
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
<section>
<br>
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="1.html">SUBSITE 1</a></li>
<li><a href="2.html">SUBSITE 2</a></li>
<li><a href="3.html">SUBSITE 3</a></li>
<li><a href="4.html">SUBSITE 4</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</section>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Buttons should find themself under header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sVge.png) How could I center this list/buttons? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please be more specific, Align to the center? Vertical center, horizontal center? How do you want it to look exactly (drawing for the wanted design layout helps).

Comment: I have put a picture so you can see what I exactly mean @tacoshy

Comment: you could also try to achieve it with `li a { display: inline-block; }` instead of block. Then they can be aligned with `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cut down your code to simplify it. I'm aware that navigation is still often tought with using a list, but with a well established use of flexboxes, grid or inline-blocks not needed. Also you dont need to wrap it into a section if it is already wrapped in navigation.

In this case I just used your links and put a div inside to emulate a button. They are set to inline-block and tehrefor behave as "text" (inline). Therefor the can be easily aligned with `text-align: center;`

```css
.naglowek {
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  min-width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#navigation a div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 130px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: aqua;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px gray;
}

#navigation a div:hover {
  color: blue;
  background: aqua;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="naglowek">
  <div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
  <div id="navigation">
    <a href="1.html"><div>SUBSITE 1</div></a>
    <a href="2.html"><div>SUBSITE 2</div></a>
    <a href="3.html"><div>SUBSITE 3</div></a>
    <a href="4.html"><div>SUBSITE 4</div></a>
  </div>
</div>
```